# Firestore .set not saving data from firebase cloud function

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to save data from my form in firestore. The collection users already exists and the document 'email' also exists already. It's not saving and nor does it give any error or messages.
Any ideas why that would happen? I am able to save data from another page though. I copied the same const admin = require('firebase-admin');
and
const db = admin.firestore();

to this page as well, exactly same. Not working:
        `let setDoc = db
            .collection('users')
            .doc(email)
            .set({'abc':'def'},{merge: true});

            // .set(Encdata,{merge: true})
            return setDoc.then(res => {
              console.log('Set: ', res);
            })
            .catch(error => {
              console.log(error);
            });`

Working from another page:

````
     let setA = docRef.set({
       'username': encDec.encrypt(user_name),
       'password' : encDec.encrypt(password),
       'email': email,
       'uid': UserID
     });```


Before and After I trigger the function, data remains the same. All instructions in the function execute fine UNTIL the control reaches the "let setDoc = db" line. After that everything just silently quits.
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description and codes, it seems you intended to overwrite a single document. Based on the Add data to Cloud Firestore documentation [set a documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document) to overwrite a single one, the first set method fit for the situation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes thats right, it was messing up my data. I figured that out - using {merge: true} now.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured this one out. Maybe because too much of screen time, but basically I was messing up the init statement
instead of
`db = admin.firestore();`

I had the statement:
`db = admin.database();` 
==> this was messing up all my references to db.
So db.collection().get() was not working.

Thanks to all who answered.
Hope this helps someone.